# Saving Offset of packet in pcap file

Tags: python

So I have a pcap file with n number of packets and I'm using **Scapy** to parse it.

I can easily iterate over each packet with `pkts = rdpcap("HTTP.cap")`, then `for p in pkts`.

What I need to do is, save the offset where that packet starts, in a variable.

I can't figure out a way to do this. I need to do this because I'm creating a custom filter which would return the packet id of the concerned packet(s). Then I have a separate list which contains `(packetid,offset)` pairs for each packetid. I can't simply use `pkts.filter()` because it would defeat the purpose of creating a custom (faster) filter.

Any help here? Is this possible to do in Scapy or should I use some other library?

Comment: I am a little confused by the question... would `for i, p in enumerate(pkts):` do the trick?

Comment: Ah, not exactly. Perhaps I should've written 'OFFSET' instead of 'LINE NUMBER' in my post. I don't suppose the packets are neatly separated into separate lines in a pcap file, so line numbers won't do the trick.